# How to wrap text into SPAN Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below format text in my file.

```
<p>
hi
<span class="start"></span>
inside span
<span class="start"></span>
</p>
```

How do I convert it into Like this

```
<p>
hi
<span class="start"></span>
<span class="wrap">inside span</span>
<span class="start"></span>
</p>
```

Edit:

What I am trying to do is

```
$('.start').next().contents().wrap('<span class="wrap"/>');
```

But it is not Working well.

Comment: You should ask a question more **specifically and also paste the code** of what you have tried so far. We can only help you if want to learn and you are trying your best to achieve something. You better check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM elements has a property nextSibling, which includes text nodes and which JQuery will be able to identify.

```
$($('.start')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span class="wrap"></span>');
```